# How to move a texture in WebGL in x-axis?

Tags: javascript, canvas, opengl-es, html5-canvas, webgl

I am able to render a image to a texture , which is rendered in the top left of the screen. Now I want to move the texture slowly right in the X-Axis and add another texture in the top-left corner, and want to do it continuously .

Now, I am able to render a single texture , but unable to move further. Can anybody help me move further ?

I am putting my code which I have done so far.

Code:

*Vertex Shader*

```
attribute vec2 a_position;
uniform vec2 u_resolution;
uniform mat3 u_matrix;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(u_matrix * vec3(a_position, 1), 1);
    v_texCoord = a_position;
}
```

*Fragment Shader*

```
precision mediump float;
// our texture
uniform sampler2D u_image;
// the texCoords passed in from the vertex shader.
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);
}
```

*Javascript*

```
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT || gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, image.width, image.height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, dataTypedArray);
//Draw the rectangle.
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Where dataTypedArray is a Uint8Array of pixels.

Next I want to move this rendered texture and add more texture previous locations . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to accomplish this is basically to draw 2 quads with 2 separate draw calls. In the first draw call, draw the first quad at desired x location, then, switch to the second texture and draw the second quad at whatever the desired location is. You do not have to alter the shader in any way.

In pseudo-js:

```
// allocate the two textures 

gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT || gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, firstTexture);
// use whatever method you want uniform/attribute/watever to upload the quad position
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, secondTexture);
// upload the second quad position
gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: After a long time reading books and doing some examples, I am little bit comfortable with WebGL, I wrote this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/rbmqqp2v/3/) , it zooms in/out on mousewheel , but pan is still a puzzle for me , can you modify the fiddle to fix the panning please?

Answer (score 0):

This is typically accomplished by translating the texture coordinates themselves. The vertex shader will often include a texture matrix:

```
attribute vec2 vertexTexCoord;  // input texture coord (s,t)
uniform mat4 TextureMatrix;     // for transforming (s,t)
varying vec2 texCoord;          // output texture coord
...
 void main() {
      gl_Position = ModelViewProjection*vec4(vertexPosition,1.0);
      texCoord = (TextureMatrix*vec4(vertexTexCoord,0.0,1.0)).st;
      ...
 }
```

The texture matrix can translate, rotate, scale,... the texture. The client JS code constructs the appropriate transform and loads the shader's texture matrix. If you wish to animate the translation then you might recompute the texture matrix at each from:

```
 ... compute s-traslation ds based on frame time ...
 Texture = new Matrix4x4;
 Texture.translate(ds, 0, 0).scale(4, 2, 1);
 ...
 gl.uniformMatrix4fv(program.TextureMatrix, false, Texture.array);
```

If you wish to involve multiple textures, then your will have to use multiple texture units and access them as needed in the fragment shader:

```
 varying vec2 texCoord;
 uniform sampler2D texUnit0;
 uniform sampler2D texUnit1;
 ...
 void main() {
     ... choose which texture you want to access based on texCoord.st
     gl_FragColor = texture2D(desiredTexUnit, texCoord);
     ...
 }
```

Take a look at [this textured donut](https://ezekiel.encs.vancouver.wsu.edu/~cs442/lectures/texture/torus/class/webgl-torus-textured/torus.html) to see the effect of scaling texture coordinates with a single texture. You'll need to perform multi-texturing to get the effect you desire.

Comment: The link to torus is a good demonstration, but how is it related to my question. I need two textures to render one after the other as a slideshow. Is my question confusing? If yes , let me know, I will try to explain in a different way

Comment: After a long time reading books and doing some examples, I am little bit comfortable with WebGL, I wrote this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Subhasish2015/rbmqqp2v/3/) , it zooms in/out on mousewheel , but pan is still a puzzle for me , can you modify the fiddle to fix the panning please?